# Inherit a folder's CONTENTS, with override?

Tags: windows-server, files-folders

So, this is going to be a total longshot, I know... but is there any way to have a folder inherit the **contents** of another folder, but also be able to add additional items of it's own, or override specific contents with it's own?

I'm thinking in programming ideas, similar to a class inheriting another class, but also adding its own method, or overriding others.

So for example, if you have a folder:

```
OriginalFolder
    SubFolder1
        ATextFile.txt { some file contents in here }
        ADiffFile.txt { some original contents in here }
    AJpgFile.jpg
```

and then define another folder as inheriting OriginalFolder, but then it also has an additional file, and has its own version of the text file, so it would wind up looking like this:

```
InheritedFolder
    SubFolder1 (inherited)
        ATextFile.txt (local) { different file contents in here }
        ADiffFile.txt (inherited)  { some original contents in here }
    SubFolder2 (local)
    AJpgFile.jpg (inherited)
```

I'm kind of guessing there isn't really, ... but ... who knows?!
So, I'm taking the shot in the dark, to see if anyone knows of a way.

I'm working in a Windows environment; the server in question where I'm looking to do this specifically is `Windows Server 2019`.

Comment: [Union mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount). For Linux see the list in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1281559/432690) (may be outdated though).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Holy crap! I really was not expecting such a thing to exist! I'm in Windows actually (updated the question), but this at least gives me a launching point to do further research. Thank you!