# How to mount FUSE (e.g. unionfs) so that all users will have access to it?

Tags: linux, mount, fuse

I am trying to use unionfs to create multiple (100+) instances of a few development tools for our development server. Here is the script I am using:

```
PROJECT=$1
DEPLOYMENT=$2
TOOL=$3

DIR_TOOL="/var/www/tools/${TOOL}"
DIR_CONFIG="/var/www/tools-instances/${PROJECT}/${DEPLOYMENT}/${TOOL}/config"
DIR_TMP="/var/www/tools-instances/${PROJECT}/${DEPLOYMENT}/${TOOL}/tmp"
DIR_MERGED="/var/www/tools-instances/${PROJECT}/${DEPLOYMENT}/${TOOL}/merged"

mkdir -p "${DIR_CONFIG}"
mkdir -p "${DIR_TMP}"
mkdir -p "${DIR_MERGED}"

unionfs -o cow "${DIR_TMP}"=RW:"${DIR_CONFIG}"=RO:"${DIR_TOOL}"=RO "${DIR_MERGED}"
```

And then use it like this:

```
create-tool-overlay.sh "project-1" "staging" "phpmyadmin"
```

Everything works fine but only for our `manager` user.
If I try to access the folder as any other user including `www-data` (who needs this access) and `root` (who should have access to everything) I get `permission denied`.
And if I try to run `ls` on this folder I get this weird output:

```
root@app-1:/var/www/tools-instances/project-1/staging/phpmyadmin# ls -al
ls: cannot access 'merged': Permission denied
total 32
drwxrwxr-x+ 5 manager manager 4096 Dec 16 15:51 .
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 manager manager 4096 Dec 14 15:29 ..
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 manager manager 4096 Dec 14 15:29 config
d?????????? ? ?       ?          ?            ? merged
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 manager manager 4096 Dec 16 15:51 tmp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unionfs` executable you used created a [filesystem in *userspace* (FUSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). The process managing the filesystem runs under a specific user (in your case: `manager`) and other users have no access. Giving access to other users is less secure. Read about [security concerns](https://superuser.com/a/1242432/432690).

You can lower the security. See `man 8 fuse`. The option `allow_root` will allow root to use the filesystem. The option `allow_other` will allow anyone to use the filesystem. These options are mutually exclusive, it seems you want the latter. Note you need to place `user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf` in order to use `allow_other` as a regular user. This is the relevant comment from the default `fuse.conf` in my Kubuntu [`formatting` mine]:

> `user_allow_other` - Using the `allow_other` mount option works fine as root, in order to have it work as user you need `user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf` as well. (This option allows users to use the `allow_other` option.) You need `allow_other` if you want users other than the owner to access a mounted fuse. This option must appear on a line by itself. There is no value, just the presence of the option.

You pass `allow_other` as (a part of) an option-argument to `-o` while invoking `unionfs`. In your case it will be like:

```
unionfs -o cow,allow_other …
```

Note if the filesystem runs under a specific regular user then it will only be able to do (to the underlying storage) what this user can do. E.g. if you run `unionfs` as `manager` and `allow_other` allows `www-data` to use the filesystem, then any file created by `www-data` will still belong to `manager` anyway. Other limitations will possibly manifest themselves.

Running the filesystem under `root` can help, but see the [already linked answer](https://superuser.com/a/1242432/432690). Running under `root` is not advised.

In general FUSE is designed as a generic way for users without root access to mount and use filesystems for *themselves*, without bothering actual admins. To use a filesystem with other users, the right way is to have support from the kernel and from an admin who can `mount`.

AFAIK it's possible to have UnionFS as a kernel module (not FUSE), but it's not in the mainline kernel, you need to build it by yourself. If I understand correctly, UnionFS implemented in the kernel should behave like you expected.

In my Kubuntu I can use OverlayFS (which is one of [alternatives](https://superuser.com/a/1281559/432690)) already present as a kernel module (not FUSE).